# Sending APNs VoIP notification return InvalidPushType

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying send a voip push notification but it's return **InvalidPushType**, how you can see in the image.

[image]

And my code to make the request with Curl PHP

```
if (defined("CURL_VERSION_HTTP2") && (curl_version()["features"] & CURL_VERSION_HTTP2) !== 0) {

     $device_token = "1302E8106AA322DE917B2D0F0FC4D656878F878E8E2FCEA9CEA153D3C80027C7";
     $body["aps"] = array(
        "alert" => "callIOS",
        "id" => "eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b",
        "nameCaller" => "Hien Nguyen",
        "handle" => "0123456789",
        "isVideo" => true
     );

     $header[] = "apns-topic: ao.medicare.app";
     $header[] = "apns-expiration: 0";
     $header[] = "apns-priority: 10";
     $header[] = "apns-push-type: voip";
     $header[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     $header[] = "apns-id: eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b";

     $ch = curl_init();
     $url = "https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com/3/device/" . $device_token;
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);             
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "VOIP.pem");
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "");

     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     $err = curl_error($ch);

     print_r(json_decode($response));
     print_r(json_decode($err));
     curl_close($ch);
  } else {
     echo "No HTTP/2 support on client.";
  }
```

I'm following the official doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns)

Edit: I try add .voip at the end of apns-topic (ao.medicare.app.voip), don't work.

Comment: Please add your code as a code block, not an image. Images cannot be copied to answers and do not work with screen readers or indexing.

Comment: And I try add .voip at the end of apns-topic (ao.medicare.app.voip) don't work... not working

Comment: Return DeviceTokenNotForTopic when add .voip at the end of apns-topic

Comment: Did you obtain the device token via the voip push registration process? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/supporting_pushkit_notifications_in_your_app

Comment: yes @Paulw11, my code in AppDelegate: **let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I was getting the wrong APNs token, the right way to get APNs token in flutter is colling this function:

```
await FlutterCallkitIncoming.getDevicePushTokenVoIP()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you linked to:

> voip:
>
> If you set this push type, the apns-topic header field must use your app’s bundle ID with .voip appended to the end.

Therefore you must specify `apns-topic` as `ao.medicare.app.voip`